# List(...) or List{ForEach(...)} the right approach in SwiftUI?

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui

I now saw a lot of different implementations in SwiftUI where a List should be displayed. Some guys did it like this:

```
List(languages, id: \.self) { language in
    Text(language.name ?? "Unknown")
}
```

others like this:

```
List {
    ForEach(languages, id: \.self) { language in
        Text(language.name ?? "Unknown")
    }
}
```

are there any advantages or disadvantages to use one or another?

Comment: The 1st variant of constructors is not available on watchOS, with ForEach - no limits. That's the end of official differences... But 1st is shorter. And just by experience, 2nd behaves sometimes differently - so just case-by-case. I use 1st as far as it works as expected, if somethings goes wrong - try second.

Comment: You can use the second if you for example also need some static content in the list, or want to make a list based on two arrays with different content types. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input This tutorial page is not actually written about this topic, but still shows a beautiful use case.